# Как правильно соединиться с бд и отправить туда данные?

Tags: php, база-данных

Я начал учить php, и столкнулся с одной проблемой:запрос в коде php не отправляется в таблицу в бд.

```
$mysql = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','register-bd');
$mysql->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `pass`, `name`) VALUES('$login', '$pass', '$name')");
$mysql->close();
```

Что тут не так? Выводится ошибка загрузки страницы HTTP ERROR 500.

Comment: Какая выводится ошибка?

Comment: $mysql->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `pass`, `name`) VALUES('{$login}', '{$pass}', '{$name}')");

Comment: @Quazimorda вы *правда* думаете что добавление кучерявых скобочек хоть что-то меняет?

Comment: @Ипатьев, ну добавлять переменные в строку, обособленную двойными кавычками я привык именно так. Впрочем, кода возвращаемой ошибки ещё не было, теперь я вижу, что дело явно в другом. Но сомнение было с самого начала, поэтому и лишь комментарий, а не ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Хороший вопрос на самом деле, на который *очень мало* нормальных ответов.

## Как правильно соединяться

При соединении помимо правильных параметров соединения с БД еще очень важно учитывать два момента:

- **кодировку соединения**, чтобы потом не возникало вопросов "у меня кракозябры в базе данных"
- **режим выброса исключений**, чтобы потом не возникало вопросов "а почему у меня ничего не работает"

Готовый пример возьмём [отсюда](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect#oop):

```
<?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    $mysqli->set_charset($charset);
} catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
     throw new \mysqli_sql_exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
}
unset($host, $db, $user, $pass, $charset); // we don't need them anymore
```

В этом коде надо заменить параметры соединения на свои и поместить его в отдельный файл. И затем инклюдить там, где нужно соединение с базой данных.

## Как отправить данные в БД

На этот вопрос тоже очень много дурацких ответов, которые создают больше прорблем, чем решают.

Чтобы **правильно** добавить данные в БД, надо

1. Написать запрос, в котором все переменные заменить на знаки вопроса
2. Подготовить запрос к выполнению
3. Привязать переменные к запросу
4. Выполнить

В итоге получаем такой код:

```
<?php
// подключаем соединение
require_once 'mysqli.php';

// создаем запрос SQL в котором все переменные заменены на знак вопроса
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `pass`, `name`) VALUES(?,?,?)";
// подготоваливаем запрос
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql); 
// привязываем переменные к запросу
// указывая тип для каждой переменной. для простоты всегда можно использовать тип "s"
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $login, $pass, $name);
// выполняем запроc
$stmt->execute();
```

при таком способе у нас **никогда не будет ошибок синтаксиса**, не говоря уже об sql инъекциях.