# появилась ошибка Unknown column 'word' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Я попытался через форму записать данные на таблицу в бд, но появляется ошибка Unknown column 'word' in 'field list'(word это условное значение логина)

```
   $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "root";
  $dbname = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (login, password)
VALUES ($login, $pass)";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: смотри мой ответ на твой другой вопрос, там написано, как исправить эту ошибку. Ну неправильно вставляешь переменные в запрос

Comment: @Ипатьев какой именно ответ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1095368/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b4-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5