# Как записать кавычки в базу данных

Tags: php, sql

у меня в переменную `$value` приходят тестовые данные, и в некоторых случаях они выглядят примерно так `J'adore`, из-за чего получаю ошибку:

> Ошибка You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'adore at line 1

Как можно разрешить данную ситуацию? При чём, нужно, чтоб в базу записалось именно в таком виде, в котором приходит.

Comment: Не подставляйте само значение в запрос. Используйте подготавливаемые выражения и привязку аргументов https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php (посмотрите примеры, вместо всех параметров ставятся `?` а потом уже задается что они значат). Аналогичный способ есть и в PDO

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1095368/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b4-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5/1095479#1095479

Comment: Интересно, что пол-года назад клиенту уже объясняли как делать запросы в БД. Но похоже обучаемость у него отрицательная

Comment: Не успел добавить ответ, но можно через PDO (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: @fedor-sg ты *действительно* думаешь, что  на этом сайте нет ответов, объясняющих, как пользоваться PDO, и обязательно нужен ещё один?

Comment: Смотря в каком контексте задан вопрос. Иногда нужен, иногда нет. Конкретно здесь спрашивают про то, как кавычку записать, но на самом деле вопрос более глобален и должен звучать как вообще правильно добавить данные в базу.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В дополнение к комментарию @Mike хочу показать вам на будущее как работать с кавычками внутри строк.
Вы можете воспользоваться функцией `addslashes()`, вот пример из документации:

```
<?php
$str = "Ваше имя O'Reilly?";

// выводит: Ваше имя O\'Reilly?
echo addslashes($str);
?>
```

И [ссылка](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.addslashes.php) на функцию

Comment: я находил на эту функцию в поисках, и она бы помогла, но мне нужно, чтоб в базу записалось именно O'Reilly, а не O\'Reilly

Comment: @KirillBulgakov Именно так в БД и запишется - посмотрите, используя клиент командной строки.

Comment: Ты можешь скольк угодно ставить флаги, но этот говнокод без соответствующего комментария не останется.

Comment: да чувак, всё что мне нужно было - это спарсить csv файл в базу, для себя, один раз, заморачиваться с pdo я не хотел, поэтому addslashes отлично решила этот вопрос, всего 3 короткие строчки кода, а ты тут развёл палемику, будто я в промышленном объёме пишу к базе прямые запросы, ты красавчик, потому что топишь за правильный код, но в данном случае мне это было не нужно