# Как в mysql добавить текст в строку по id и в нужный столбец?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть код удаления нужного столбца с текстом из БД:

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `users` SET `summary`=NULL WHERE id=$id");
```

Он удаляет текст в столбце summary,  как мне теперь добавить туда другой текст не создавая новую строку?

Пытался сделать так но не катит!

```
mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `users` SET `summary`=`summary` WHERE id=$id");
```

Здесь просто код добавления в БД!

```
$conn -> query("INSERT INTO `users` 
(`caption`,`summary`,`author_post`) VALUES
('$caption','$summary','$author_post')" );
```

Comment: вот более корректный дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1095368/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b4-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5/1095479#1095479

Comment: Проблема в том что ты неправильно пишешь запросы. Нельзя переменную пихать прямо в текст запроса - от этого происходят все ошибки. Смотри по приведенным ссылкам, как правильно выполнять запросы. И кстати удалять содержимое сначала не ну нужно. Просто выполняешь **один** запрос update.