# не работает id в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql

Я создал БД в MySQL из одной таблицы, где также присутствует id. id я обозначил как unique, и в php после соединения, когда записывал данные формы туда, не обращался к нему. id должен быть счетчиком, поэтому к нему обращаться не стоит в php. Я это и сделал, но вышла проблема "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value"
код:

```
    $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "root";
  $dbname = "register-bd";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (login, password, name)
VALUES ('$login', '$pass','$name')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Значения id в MySQL:int(11), атрибут:UNSIGNED, индекс:unique

Comment: Хммм... А вы указывали `primary key`  и `auto increment`? пример: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/primary_keys.php

Comment: Я тебе уже [писал, как привильно соединяться и добавлять данные в базу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1095368/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b4-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5). А ты опять за свой говнокод.